# Android studio error executing "am start" and cannot attach debugger

Tags: android, android-studio

When I click the run or debug icon in android studio I get the following error.

```
04/28 08:03:33: Launching app
No local changes, not deploying APK
$ adb shell am start -D -n "com.example.sam.errorline/com.example.sam.errorline.MainActivity" -a android.intent.action.MAIN -c android.intent.category.LAUNCHER
Error while executing: am start -D -n "com.example.sam.errorline/com.example.sam.errorline.MainActivity" -a android.intent.action.MAIN -c android.intent.category.LAUNCHER
Starting: Intent { act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] cmp=com.example.sam.errorline/.MainActivity }

Error while Launching activity
```

The app starts on the emulator but when I try to debug there is a dialog on the emulator that says it is waiting for a dubugger to attach. A debugger never attaches.

Could it not be finding an activity? My manifest looks like this.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.sam.errorline">

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
</manifest>
```

My activity looks like this...

```
package com.example.sam.errorline;

import android.content.pm.ApplicationInfo;
import android.os.Build;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.webkit.CookieManager;
import android.webkit.WebSettings;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private WebView view;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        view = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.activity_main_webview);

        WebSettings settings = view.getSettings();
        settings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        settings.setAllowFileAccess(true);
        // I think these were default enabled (with no option) before JELLY_BEAN
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN) {
            settings.setAllowFileAccessFromFileURLs(true);
            settings.setAllowUniversalAccessFromFileURLs(true);
        }

        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) {
            if (0 != (getApplicationInfo().flags &= ApplicationInfo.FLAG_DEBUGGABLE)) {
                WebView.setWebContentsDebuggingEnabled(true);
            }
        }
        view.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
        view.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/www/index.html");
    }
}
```

Comment: Check the logcat output for additional messages.

Answer (score 0):

It appears to be an android studio bug. When a create a new project called "Errortest" I have the same problem. Other names work fine.